# group_concat with rollup messes up the last row

Tags: mysql

I've a table created with -

```
CREATE TABLE sales(year INT, country VARCHAR(20), product VARCHAR(32), profit INT);
```

Inserted some values in it and tried to use this query

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(country) as country, year, SUM(profit) AS profit
FROM sales
GROUP BY year ASC WITH ROLLUP;
```

Result obtained -

```
country                                       | year  | profit
----------------------------------------------|-------|----------
India,Australia                               | 2014  |  50
----------------------------------------------|-------|----------
New Zealand                                   | 2015  |  20
----------------------------------------------|-------|----------
United States                                 | 2016  |  150
----------------------------------------------|-------|----------
India,Australia,New Zealand,United States     | NULL  |  220
```

As seen - last row concatenates all the row values. Is there a way I could replace only last row value with NULL as done for year?

I need to use `GROUP_CONCAT` for `country` and cannot `groupby` for `country` to get the `NULL`. Just want to replace the last row value with an empty val.

Comment: This is how `WITH ROLLUP` works. You can detect the row in the client code (PHP) and use `NULL` instead of the big list of countries. It is the row having `NULL` in the `year` column.

Comment: Based on answers posted, I can go for it, but really looking for rollup answers as I don't want to modify much in my code.

Answer (score 1):

you should avoid the  rollup

```
  select country, year, profit
  from (
    SELECT '1' seq, GROUP_CONCAT(country) as country, year, SUM(profit) AS profit
    FROM sales
    GROUP BY seq, year ;

    union 

    select '2', null, null, SUM(profit)
    SELECT 
    FROM sales
  ) t
  order bt t.seq, t.country
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This is just an example. My actualy query i extremely large, is there any rollup possibility to just empty the last row ?

Comment: The rollup work as you see in the sample  .. if you need  a total result at bottom well formed  you could us  the union as i suggested  in my answer

Answer (score 1):

GROUP BY WITH ROLLUP is a bit tricky to use and sometimes you get wierd results.

I advise you to use UNION and a second query to get the results you need.

```
SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = @@max_allowed_packet

SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(country) as country, year, SUM(profit) AS profit
FROM sales
GROUP BY year ASC

UNION ALL 

SELECT NULL, NULL, SUM(profit) AS profit FROM sales
```

Comment: This is just an example. My actualy query i extremely large, is there any rollup possibility to just empty the last row ?  Thanks for answering

Comment: @jitendrapurohit  Just use UNION ALL SELECT NULL, NULL, SUM(profit) AS profit FROM sales to simulate the ROLLUP this is much eazier to empty out the last row.. GROUP BY WITH ROLLUP doesnt have that feature.